# Return all foreign keys used in this queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm struggling to explain what I want to do (hence I am unable to actually find a post about this) so hopefully someone can help me out.

I have couple models and all are tied to the Product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)
    item_type = models.ForeignKey(ItemType)
    colour = models.ManyToManyField(Colour)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='')
    product_name_pl = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='')
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    product_comment = models.CharField(max_length = 300, default='', blank=True)
    product_comment_pl = models.CharField(max_length = 300, default='', blank=True)
    display_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.product_name
```

e.g.

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    collection_name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default='m')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/collections/', blank=True)
    collection_type = models.ManyToManyField(CollectionType)
    display_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=999)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.collection_name
```

or

```
class Colour(models.Model):
    colour_name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default='m')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/types/', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
    return self.colour_name
```

The idea is when I retrieve a set of products by using the Collection, I want to have a list of available colours in the current selection and maybe a count of how many of each product each colour has.

What I'm mostly looking for is a point towards a correct direction in the queryset documentation if that's possible to do, not expecting a full solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you have collection then you can access to products in collection via related name:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    colour = models.ManyToManyField(Colour)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, related_name = 'products)
```

Then you have access colors when from Colletion:

```
collection = Collection.object.all.first()

for product in collection.products:
    print(product.colour) # print product colors queryset. You can convert it to list if required.
    print(product.colour.count()) # how many colors you have
```

P.S. Better rename colour to colours in Product. It will be easier to understand that it is plural.